# Right-censored cash flows and survival analysis

Tags: survival, finance, censoring, mortality

I am doing survival analysis on a disability claims dataset - each row tells me how long a person has been on claim and whether they have gone off claim yet. Ultimately I am interested in predicting the full benefits that will be paid to a given person.

Usually the benefit amount is a deterministic, known-in-advance function of the time on claim, so it is sufficient to simply predict the claim duration using conventional survival analysis. However, this isn't always the case. For example, a person may have a partial disability, which reduces the amount paid, but we won't know their percentage of partial disability when the policy is issued.

I can think of two potential ways to address this complication:

1. Add more model complexity. For example, fit a model that predicts the likelihood of going on partial disability based on past data, and use this to modify the expected benefit outlay. If the "average" claim (given the relevant covariates) is a 70% partial claim, multiply the expected benefit outlay for that claim by 70%.
2. Modify the survival analysis. Instead of using a right-censored duration dataset, I would use a right-censored cash flow dataset, telling me how much has been paid so far and whether we are done paying yet.

The second approach is attractive to me for its simplicity, but I'm not sure of the statistical implications. Are there any statistical frameworks I might consider for analysis of "right-censored cash flows"?

I suspect at the end of the day I'm going to use something like a piecewise exponential model with quasi-Poisson or other quasi-likelihood, but maybe there's something else I'm not thinking about here.